# Use WebRTC video call SDK for load/stress/performance testing

Tags: jmeter, webrtc, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter

I have WebRTC video call SDK and WebRTC server. I wanted to Register more than 10000 user virtually to WebRTC server and do the video call in between them by using my SDK. Basically I wanted to do load/stress/performance testing using my SDK.

Could you please suggest me how can we do the load/stress/performance testing using my own WebRTC video call SDK ?